# Why do people refuse to acknowledge the Holocaust?

Tags: nazi-germany, jews, holocaust

A lot of people nowadays are denying the Holocaust as a hoax and overblown Jewish lie.

I read somewhere that Harry Truman (or Eisenhower) thought that people would not believe the Holocaust happened and that he had troops take multiple pictures of the death camps as proof that such atrocities happened.

Neo Nazis, of course, don't believe it happened and always scapegoat Jews for *making up* the events of the Holocaust, but other people who are students or normal folks who learned much of the Holocaust somehow start to disbelieve it happened and start justifying and defending the Nazis concerning the Camps and brutality against the Jews and such.

Why do so many people refuse to believe what is in front of them and deny the undeniable evidence that clearly show that Jews were being persecuted?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this can be resolved through historical methods.  I suspect that the answer is found in psychology, not history; this question may be closed as being outside the scope of H:SE.

Comment: It was Eisenhower, who did visit one of the camps shortly after its liberation. Truman never visited the camps prior to them being (somewhat) cleaned up.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace isnt this question just as valid here as it would be in psychology?

Comment: Questions about soft sciences other than history are out of scope per [ask]. Questions that cannot be solved through the application of historical sources and methods are out of scope for H:SE.

Comment: A changing of tense - "What reasons have people historically/in the past cited for holocaust denialism?" could allow for it.

Answer (score 14):

One of my uncles was an intelligence officer assigned to evaluate and document the camps.  He also took pictures for his private albums.  He retired after 30 years as a colonel, and would offer to show his WW II souvenirs to visitors. I once (~1990) made the mistake of looking through his photo albums, and had nightmares for months. The pictures of the living were very disturbing, but so were the pits filled with the dead. As they say, seeing is believing.

A few years later I visited Dachau; it gave me the creeps.  It's really hard to believe that people could do the things that were done.

[image]

Dachau concentration camp; if too graphic, feel free to remove.

Photo from [Dachau concentration camp memorial: A chilling reminder of Nazi atrocities](http://ilatimes.com/article.php?id=50167)

Comment: [This site](https://www.ushmm.org/confront-antisemitism/holocaust-denial-and-distortion) provides information on holocaust distortion and denial.

Comment: Note, that very few if any Holocaust deniers deny the existence of the camps or that people died there (of course, they disagree about the exact numbers). The contested aspects are the gas chambers, burning people alive, mass executions, etc., by claiming that most or all people who died in the Nazi concentration camps died of illness, exhaustion or malnutrition, just as millions died in the Soviet Gulags without needing any gas chambers, and how other millions of civilians died in Europe during the war without being interned into concentration camps.

Comment: I am Jewish.  Members of my family were buried alive by the Nazis, according to witnesses.

Comment: This appears to be a dead link now- could you update it?

Comment: @Puppy - link refreshed.